# Typo3 Login-error or session timed-out?

Tags: typo3

I get this error very quick when I log into Typo3 4.1.3. After 5 min Typo3 give me this error and it is impossible to work in the Backend. I've tried with Chromium and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using multiple proxy servers so that you access the TYPO3 installation using different IPs?
If yes, change the *lockIP* setting in the Install Tool.

BTW: Please upgrade TYPO3! The 4.1 branch is out of maintenance since >1 year and 4.1.3 contains several security issues!

Comment: No, but my installation is in a subfolder not the root of htdocs. My lockIP setting is 4 which is the default setting. Should I change this?